# Term for the ratio of ciphertext to plaintext size?

Tags: encryption, terminology

Is there a term that determines the ratio of size of ciphertext $|c|$ and plaintext $|n|$? I vaguely recollect reading it as *scale out* factor. Is there a better term? Or a popular term for this?

Comment: Ciphertext expansion?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Ciphertext expansion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ciphertext_expansion), or expansion ratio are terms used to indicate this.